# I am having trouble cloning a linked list, what is the problem in my code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, singly-linked-list

Structure of `Node`:

```
class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node *arb;
    Node(int value){
        data=value;
        next=NULL;
        arb=NULL;
    }
};
```

Now, I wrote the following code, but I am getting a **segmentation fault** runtime error. I can't find out what is causing this error.

```
Node *copyList(Node *head)
    {
        Node* ptr=head;
        Node *temp;
        Node *clonehead; 
        Node *clonetail;
        while(ptr!=NULL){
            temp=ptr->next;
            Node* newnode=new Node(ptr->data);
            if(ptr==head){
                clonehead=newnode;
                clonetail=clonehead;
            }
            else{
                clonetail->next=newnode;
                clonetail=newnode;
            }
            clonetail->arb=ptr->arb;
            ptr->next=clonetail;
            ptr=temp;
        }
        ptr=clonehead;
        while(ptr!=NULL){
            temp=ptr->arb;
            ptr->arb=temp->next;
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        return clonehead;
    }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Link to the problem: [Clone a linked list with next and random pointer](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/clone-a-linked-list-with-next-and-random-pointer/1#)

Comment: What is the runtime error? `clonetail->arb=ptr->arb;` looks like a potential problem, since it's copying a pointer, but I don't know what `arb` is supposed to be.

Comment: @ChrisMM, arb is a pointer to a random node.

Comment: Also, `ptr->next=clonetail;` seems wrong. Copying that node into the wrong list.

Comment: The most likely problem is that you free the original arbitrary data. Since the clone has a copy of the pointer, but not a copy of what it points to, you now have a dangling pointer. In C++ you should use a smart pointer to mitigate this problem.

Comment: The problem is likely here: `temp=ptr->arb; ptr->arb=temp->next;`. `ptr->arb` could be null, you store it in `temp`, then dereference it with `temp->next`.

Comment: @Welbog thanks. I had just totally forgotten that.

Comment: `ptr->next=clonetail;` modifies the original list to now point into the cloned list. The last `while` makes no sense either. Try changing the code to `Node *copyList(const Node *head)` and fix all the constness errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code:

- `clonetail->arb=ptr->arb;`

  The instructions you provided are very clear that the `next` and `arb` pointers in the cloned list need to point at nodes in the cloned list, not at nodes in the original list.
- `ptr->next=clonetail;`

  You are modifying the `next` pointer of the nodes in the original list, which you should not be doing at all.
- This code makes no sense at all:

  ```
  while(ptr!=NULL){
      temp=ptr->arb;
      ptr->arb=temp->next;
      ptr=ptr->next;
  }
  ```

  You are iterating through the cloned list, and for each `arb` (which is pointing at a node in the original list, not in the cloned list), you are updating it to point at the referred node's `next` node rather than at the referred node itself.  You are not taking into account the possibility that `arb` may be NULL, or the fact that the cloned `arb`s are pointing at nodes in the wrong list to begin with.

Since each node's `arb` is pointing at a random node in the same list, you can't clone the `arb`s in the same loop that is cloning the nodes, as any given `arb` may be referring to a later node that hasn't been cloned yet.

To clone the `arb`s, you would have to first finish cloning the nodes from the original list, and then iterate through the cloned list updating its `arb`s to point at the correct nodes within the cloned list, not the original list.  I believe this is what you are *attempting* to do, but you are not doing it correctly.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node *arb;

    Node(int value){
        data = value;
        next = NULL;
        arb = NULL;
    }
};

Node* resolveNode(Node *head, Node *clone, Node *target)
{
    while (head && clone){
        if (head == target)
            return clone;
        head = head->next;
        clone = clone->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

Node* copyList(Node *head)
{
    Node *clonehead = NULL; 
    Node *ptr, **newnode = &clonehead;

    ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL){
        *newnode = new Node(ptr->data);
        newnode = &((*newnode)->next);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    Node *cloneptr = clonehead;
    ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL){
        cloneptr->arb = resolveNode(head, clonehead, ptr->arb);
        cloneptr = cloneptr->next;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    return clonehead;
}
```

Alternatively, if you can spare some extra memory, you can avoid the repeated list iterations in the 2nd loop by using a `std::(unordered_)map` to keep track of which nodes in the original list correspond to which nodes in the cloned list, eg:

```
#include <map>

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node *arb;

    Node(int value){
        data = value;
        next = NULL;
        arb = NULL;
    }
};

Node* copyList(Node *head)
{
    Node *clonehead = NULL; 
    Node *ptr, **newnode = &clonehead;
    std::map<Node*, Node*> node_lookup;

    ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL){
        *newnode = new Node(ptr->data);
        node_lookup.insert(std::make_pair(ptr, *newnode);
        newnode = &((*newnode)->next);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    Node *cloneptr = clonehead;
    ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL){
        cloneptr->arb = node_lookup[ptr->arb];
        cloneptr = cloneptr->next;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    return clonehead;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already did using hashmap but I wanted to do without hashmap.